# Dismiss apple push notifications when clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

So it's a pretty straight forward problem. My server sends an APN to the iOS device, I can click on the notification and the app launches and everything works as it should, but the notification never gets dismissed, it just sits there in notification centre.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Apologies if this has been answered before, I've searched all over stack and only found reference to local notifications.

**Edit**

Ok, so when I put

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber=0;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions it dismisses any old notifications when the app is launched (and no this doesn't happen by default when the app launched anyway), but when I put it in any of the other delegate methods that get called when the app becomes active like applicationDidBecomeActive: it doesn't work?

This is making very little sense...

Comment: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];`

Comment: The iOS System is supposed to handle removing notifications from the center once tapped. I'm creating an app with APNS right now and every time I click the notification, it disappears. (I'm not doing anything special.) Sounds like you *might* be facing a bug. @meda 's comments also won't help you remove the notification itself. They remove the badge icon number and just cancel *local* notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Adding in:

```
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
```

into applicationDidBecomeActive: did the trick!